# What all fits into 4532 "Container, Cupboard"?

Tags: building

On Bricklink, [the entry for 4532](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4532#T=C) (a container) lists several parts that fit, but it currently doesn't even list 4536 (a drawer). What else fits into 4532? Better yet, what are some "illegal" techniques that can be used with 4532? Is there something that can be used as a flat panel in conjunction with a single 4536?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[The door](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4533) that is listed as compatible can be attached with its handle inside to make a smooth surface at the front. It could become hard to open however.

Comment: Similarly, it is possible to insert drawers upside-down, however only the top drawer will be able to close all the way.